# After updating Gulp from 3 to 4.0.2 tasks not running in correct sequence

Tags: javascript, gulp

//Initially I was using Gulp V3 and had a code snippet as below:

```
gulp.task('b',function(){
  return (//something)
});

gulp.task('a',['b'],function(){
return gulp.src (//do something)
});
```

this was running as expected as below on calling gulp a:

- starting b
- finished b
- starting a
- finished a

I updated my gulp file to v4 and updated the code snippet as below:
Gulp v4:

```
 gulp.task('b',function(){
      return (//something)
    });

gulp.task('a',gulp.series('b'),function a(){
return gulp.src (//do something)
});
```

However the tasks are running now as below:

- starting a
- starting b
- finished a
- finished b

From the numerous blogs I have gone through they all mention that 'b' task should be picked up first.
I do not understand why 'a' task is being picked up first and this is not as expected for me.
Can anyone please guide?
Also I would like 'b' task to finish and then 'a' task to start.
Appreciate help.

Thanks Mark. On checking your comment, I now updated my gulp file as below:
Gulp v4:

```
gulp.task('a',gulp.series('b',function a(){
return gulp.src (//do something)
}));
```

However the tasks are running now as below on calling gulp a:

- starting a
- starting b
- finished b
- starting a
- finished a
- finished a
- So now I have a running twice which is not as expected and I expect b to start first while I have a starting first

Thanks Mark. For clarity I have renamed the function as a1:

```
gulp.task('b',function(){
      return (//something)
    });
gulp.task('a',gulp.series('b',function a1(){
return gulp.src (//do something)
}));
```

I want to have b to start & finish first. Can you help how to get that? This currently gives:

- starting a
- starting b
- finished b
- starting a1
- finished a1
- finished a

Comment: Okay, you have a task named `a` and a function named `a` so it is confusing.  There is no reason to name that interior function - note that I removed it in my answer below.  But you can keep it if you want.  But the first and last `a` in your list are referring to task `a` and the other two `a`'s are referring to the function `a`.  In my comment below they are the `<anonymous>`.   If you change one of the names it will be more obvious.

Comment: Thanks Mark. But can you help with how do I get b to start & finish first ?I edited the question & my code with renamed function for clarity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is still not proper gulp v4 syntax:

```js
gulp.task('a',gulp.series('b'),function a(){
  return gulp.src (//do something)
});
```

`gulp.task` takes only **two** arguments, not three as you have.  Try this instead:

```js
gulp.task('a', gulp.series('b', function () {
  return gulp.src (//do something)
}));
```

Comment: Thanks Mark....but this is now working as: starting a, starting b, finished b, starting a, finished a, finished a. Which is still not as expected. I am running gulp a.

Comment: I tried as recommended here: https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/1392 but that did not make any difference

Comment: I get the expected `starting a, starting b, finished b, starting '<anonymous>'..., finished '<anonymous>'..., finished a`.  You should edit your question to show exactly what you are using now.

Comment: Thanks Mark I have edited the question to how I am using it now and the issues I am facing currently. Appreciate your help